# los ficheros borran la informacion almacenada si cierro el programa

Tags: c

Este es un login con opcion para iniciar Sesion y crear un nuevo Usuario, la dificultad que presento es que cuando creo un usuario para poder acceder al menuPrincipal los ficheros que almacen los datos que se registran se vacian

```
int main() {
struct Usuario usuario;
struct Planilla planilla;
struct RegistroRetenciones registroRetenciones;
int opcion;

if (!cargarUsuarioDesdeArchivo(&usuario)) {
    printf("No se pudo cargar la informacion del usuario.\n");
}

do {
    system("cls");
    
    gotoxy(40,4);printf("=====================================\n");
    gotoxy(40,5);printf("            Bienvenido al Sistema\n");
    gotoxy(40,6);printf("=====================================\n");
    gotoxy(40,8);printf("1. Iniciar Sesion\n");
    gotoxy(40,10);printf("2. Crear Nuevo Usuario\n");
    gotoxy(40,12);printf("Seleccione una opcion: ");
    scanf("%d", &opcion);
    switch (opcion) {
        case 1:
            system("cls");
            if (iniciarSesion(&usuario)) {
                
                menuPrincipal(&planilla, &registroRetenciones);// Usuario inicio sesion exitosamente, acceder al menu principal
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            system("cls");
            crearNuevoUsuario(&usuario, &planilla, &registroRetenciones);
            break;
        default:
            gotoxy(40,20);printf("Opcion invalida. Intente de nuevo.\n");
            system("pause");
            getch();
            break;
    }
} while (opcion != 2);

return 0;}
```

el  menuPrincipal es este, donde si ingreso la opcion de registrar empleado y guardo dichos datos del empleado, al cerrar el programa y volver iniciar sesion con el usuario creado el fichero del sistema de planillas se borra

```
      void menuPrincipal(struct Planilla *planilla, struct RegistroRetenciones *registroRetenciones) {

int opcion;

do {
    system("cls");
    color(hConsole, 7);
    gotoxy(39, 3); printf("==============================\n");
    gotoxy(39, 4); printf("||                          ||\n");
    gotoxy(39, 5); printf("||   Sistema de planillas   ||\n");
    gotoxy(39, 6); printf("||                          ||\n");
    gotoxy(39, 7); printf("==============================\n\n\n");

    color(hConsole, 6);
    gotoxy(26, 9); printf("-------------------------------------------------------");
    gotoxy(26, 10); printf("|             1. Registro de empleados                |\n");
    gotoxy(26, 11); printf("|           2. Mantenimiento de empleados             |\n");
    gotoxy(26, 12); printf("|   3. Registro/mantenimiento de retenciones de ley   |\n");
    gotoxy(26, 13); printf("|          4. Informe de planillas mensuales          |\n");
    gotoxy(26, 14); printf("|          5. Informe de planillas quincenales        |\n");
    gotoxy(26, 15); printf("|              6. Registro de descuentos              |\n");
    gotoxy(26, 16); printf("|                     7. Salir                        |\n");
    gotoxy(26, 17); printf("-------------------------------------------------------");
    printf("\n\n");
    gotoxy(26, 18); printf("-------------------------------------------------------");
    gotoxy(26, 19); printf("|               Ingrese una opcion:                   |\n");
    gotoxy(26, 20); printf("-------------------------------------------------------");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &opcion);

    switch (opcion) {
        case 1:
            registro_empleados(planilla);
            getch();
            break;
        case 2:
            mantenimiento_empleados(planilla);
            getch();
            break;
        case 3:
            mantenimiento_retenciones(registroRetenciones);
            getch();
            break;
        case 4:
            informe_planillas_mensuales(planilla, registroRetenciones);
            getch();
            break;
        case 5:
            informe_planillas_semanales(planilla, registroRetenciones);
            getch();
            break;
        case 6:
            system("cls");
            char dui_empleado[10];
            fflush(stdin);
            printf("Ingrese el DUI del empleado al que desea descontar los dias: ");
            scanf("%s", dui_empleado);
            fflush(stdin);
            descontar_dias_empleado(planilla, dui_empleado);
            getch();
            break;
        case 7:
            printf("\n\n\nSaliendo del programa...\n");
            break;
        default:
            color(hConsole, 4);
            printf("\nOpcion invalida.\n");
            getch();
            break;
    }
} while (opcion != 7);
   }
```

tanto los usuarios como la planilla hacen uso de ficheros

```
         int cargarUsuarioDesdeArchivo(struct Usuario *usuario) {
FILE *archivo = fopen("usuario.txt", "r");
if (archivo == NULL) {
    return 0; // No se pudo abrir el archivo
}
fscanf(archivo, "Nombre: %s\nUsuario: %s\nClave: %s\n", usuario->nombre, usuario->usuario, usuario->clave);
fclose(archivo);
return 1; // Carga exitosa
  }



      void guardarUsuarioEnArchivo(const struct Usuario *usuario) {
FILE *archivo = fopen("usuario.txt", "w");
if (archivo != NULL) {
   fprintf(archivo, "Nombre: %s\nUsuario: %s\nClave: %s\n", usuario->nombre, usuario->usuario, usuario->clave);
    fclose(archivo);
}
   }
    void crearNuevoUsuario(struct Usuario *usuario, struct Planilla *planilla, struct RegistroRetenciones *registroRetenciones) {
int attempts = 0;
int contrasena_correcta = 0;  // Variable para verificar si la contraseña es correcta

color(hConsole, 7);

do {
    system("cls"); // Limpia la consola
    color(hConsole, 7);
    gotoxy(40, 4);printf("=====================================");
    gotoxy(40, 5);printf("         Crear Nuevo Usuario ");
    gotoxy(40, 6);printf("=====================================");
 
    gotoxy(40, 8);printf("Nombre:");
    gotoxy(40, 10);scanf("%s", usuario->nombre);
    gotoxy(40, 12); printf("Usuario:");
    scanf("%s", usuario->usuario);

    generarClaveAleatoria(usuario->clave);

    gotoxy(40, 15);printf("Ingrese la Contrasena generada: %s\n", usuario->clave);

    guardarUsuarioEnArchivo(usuario);  // Guarda el usuario antes de verificar la contraseña

    char contrasena_ingresada[100];
    gotoxy(40, 16);printf("Confirme la Contrasena: ");
    scanf("%s", contrasena_ingresada);

    if (strcmp(contrasena_ingresada, usuario->clave) == 0) {

        menuPrincipal(planilla, registroRetenciones);
         return;
       
    } else {
        color(hConsole, 4);
        gotoxy(35, 20);
        printf("La contrasena ingresada no coincide. Creacion de usuario cancelada.\n");

        attempts++;
        
        if (attempts >= MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
            gotoxy(35, 21);printf("Has alcanzado el numero maximo de intentos. Por favor, intenta de nuevo mas tarde.\n");
            for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
             gotoxy(35,22);   printf("Puedes volver a intentarlo en %d segundos... ", i); // \r mueve el cursor al inicio de la línea
                fflush(stdout); // Limpia el buffer de salida
                sleep(1); // Espera 1 segundo
            }
            attempts = 0; // Reinicia el contador de intentos
        }
    }
   getch();
} while (contrasena_correcta != 1);  // Salir del bucle si la contraseña es correcta
 }



     int iniciarSesion(struct Usuario *usuario) {
char usuario_ingresado[50];
char clave_ingresada[6];
int attempts = 0;

do {
    system("cls"); // Limpia la consola
    color(hConsole, 7);
    gotoxy(40,4);printf("=====================================\n");
    gotoxy(40,5);printf("         Crear Nuevo Usuario \n");
    gotoxy(40,6);printf("=====================================\n");
    fflush(stdin);
    gotoxy(40,9); printf("Usuario: ");
    scanf("%49s", usuario_ingresado); // Limita la entrada a 49 caracteres
    gotoxy(40,11);printf("Contrasena: ");
    scanf("%5s", clave_ingresada); // Limita la entrada a 5 caracteres

    if (strcmp(usuario_ingresado, usuario->usuario) == 0 && strcmp(clave_ingresada, usuario->clave) == 0) {
        color(hConsole, 6);
       gotoxy(40,14); printf("¡Inicio de sesion exitoso!\n");
        return 1; // Retorna 1 en caso de éxito
    } else {
        color(hConsole, 4);
       gotoxy(40,14);printf("Inicio de sesion fallido. Usuario o contrasena incorrectos.\n");
        attempts++;
        if (attempts >= MAX_ATTEMPTS) {
            printf("Has alcanzado el numero maximo de intentos. Por favor, intenta de nuevo mas tarde.\n");
            for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--) {
             gotoxy(40,16);   printf("\rPuedes volver a intentarlo en %d segundos... ", i); // \r mueve el cursor al inicio de la línea
                fflush(stdout); // Limpia el buffer de salida
                sleep(1); // Espera 1 segundo
            }
            attempts = 0; // Reinicia el contador de intentos
        }
        // Limpia las variables para el próximo intento
        usuario_ingresado[0] = '\0';
        clave_ingresada[0] = '\0';
    }
    getch();
} while (1);
    }
```

fichero de planilla

```
 void guardar_planilla(struct Planilla *planilla) {
FILE *archivo_planilla = fopen("planilla.dat", "wb");
if (archivo_planilla == NULL) {
    color(hConsole, 4);
    printf("[Error al abrir el archivo de la planilla.]\n");
    return;
}
fwrite(planilla, sizeof(struct Planilla), 1, archivo_planilla);
fclose(archivo_planilla);
   }

      void cargar_planilla(struct Planilla *planilla) {
FILE *archivo_planilla = fopen("planilla.dat", "rb");
if (archivo_planilla == NULL) {
    color(hConsole, 4);
    printf("[No se encontro un archivo de planilla existente.]\n");
    // Si el archivo no existe, inicializa una planilla vacía
    planilla->cantidad_empleados = 0;
    planilla->retenciones.porcentaje_afp = 0.0;
    planilla->retenciones.porcentaje_isss = 0.0;
    return;
}
fread(planilla, sizeof(struct Planilla), 1, archivo_planilla);
fclose(archivo_planilla);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El modo de apertura que especificas para el archivo implica borrado de datos:

```
FILE *archivo = fopen("usuario.txt", "w");
```

Puedes verlo en la documentación de la [función `fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fopen):

| Modo | Significado | Explicación | Si el archivo existe… | Si el archivo no existe… |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `"r"` | lectura | Abre un archivo para lectura | lee desde el inicio | devuelve `NULL` y establece error |
| `"w"` | escritura | Crea un archivo para escritura | **destruye el contenido** | crea un nuevo archivo |
| `"a"` | anexar | Anexa a un archivo | escribe al final | crea un nuevo archivo |